# How to embed in a viewcontroller without tab bar when the parent is a tab bar viewcontroller?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My current hierarchy is:

1. `Tab bar controller`
2. `Navigation controller`
3. A `UIViewController`
4. Another `UIViewController`

It shows tab bars at the second `UIViewController` (so number 4 in the list). I want to remove that tab bar, but I want to keep the navigation at the top. This is because the first `UIViewController` (number 3 in the list) holds a `tableview`, and when a user clicks on a cell it goes to the second `UIViewController` and I want to keep a back button.

An example is when you open WhatsApp, you have a list of conversations (left side of image). When you click on a conversation, the tab bar buttons at the bottom are gone (right side of image). I can hide them in the second `UIViewController`, but it causes some glitches. I am sure there is a better solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In presented/pushed viewController's `viewDidLoad`, or in the storyboard, set the view controller's [`hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621863-hidesbottombarwhenpushed) to `true`.